# Merge rows together if : is present shell script

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have data in below format in a text file.

```
desc            : Abced ONE 12345678 Suites YUITREWQ & RTYUIO Mana
gement
ldesc            : Abced ONE 12345678 Suites YUITREWQ & RTYUIO Man
agement (BCD-WQ-UIO, BCD-WQ-BN)
date                          :
```

I am trying to get the output in below format .

```
desc                          : Abced ONE 12345678 Suites YUITREWQ & RTYUIO Management
ldesc                          : Abced ONE 12345678 Suites YUITREWQ & RTYUIO Management (BCD-WQ-UIO, BCD-WQ-BN)
```

Basically I want any row which has colon but nothing following a colon should be deleted and if any row doesn't have a colon it should be merged with previous row including space if any.

I tried using awk but I am unable to proceed.

Regards.

Comment: can there be 3+ lines to merge? if `awk '/:$/{next} {ORS = /:/ ? "" : "\n"} 1' file` doesn't work, then consider giving better input sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To merge a line with the previous line, you must avoid printing the newline until you know whether to merge or not.  Don't forget printing the final newline when you reach the end of the file!

```
awk '/:./ { printf "%s", $0; pending=1; next }
     /:$/ { if (pending) printf "\n"; pending=0; next }
     pending { printf "%s\n", $0; pending=0 }
     END { if (pending) printf "\n" }' file
```

Comment: Hi, The problem with this is that it removes all new line . So all data comes in a single line.

Comment: It seemed to work with the test data in the question. Can you show data for which it does what you are describing?

Comment: Actually, I found one corner case which was wrong, and I have updated the code accordingly now. Sorry about that.

Comment: Still it merges the next line and output is displayed in single line.

Comment: On what sample data? Like I said, I have tested it on the sample in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your file name `exp1.txt`

```
awk -F: 'length($2) { print $0 }' exp1.txt
```

You will got your expect result!

my output:

```
(public)landpacks-MacBook-Pro:stackoverflow frank$ cat exp1.txt 
desc            : Abced ONE 12345678 Suites YUITREWQ & RTYUIO Mana
gement
ldesc            : Abced ONE 12345678 Suites YUITREWQ & RTYUIO Man
agement (BCD-WQ-UIO, BCD-WQ-BN)
date                          :
(public)landpacks-MacBook-Pro:stackoverflow frank$ awk -F: 'length($2) { print $0 }' exp1.txt 
desc            : Abced ONE 12345678 Suites YUITREWQ & RTYUIO Mana
ldesc            : Abced ONE 12345678 Suites YUITREWQ & RTYUIO Man
(public)landpacks-MacBook-Pro:stackoverflow frank$
```

Comment: It is not working . May be I was not clear with data . I have corrected the data again.

Comment: @user2854333 If it's work, please accept the answer! tks~

Comment: This doesn't do anything to merge a lone colonless line to the previous line.

Comment: This will only eliminate the data not merge it .. for an instance I thougt it worked but when i passed it to larger set of data it didnt .

Comment: @user2854333 I can't understand your question, your expect result from such simple describer! if you can upload more data or more example input/output, maybe we can make easy to fixed!

Comment: Hi Frank. If you look at your output which you shared . desc instead of merging next row it is just eliminating the next row .